# Extend Haskell module

Tags: haskell, module, libraries

Is there any way to extend library module in Haskell?

For example, I would like to add `firstToLower` function to `Data.String`. When I create my own `Data.String` it masks library one:

```
module Data.String where

import Prelude
import Data.Char (toLower)

firstToLower :: String -> String
firstToLower (c:cs) = toLower c : cs
firstToLower "" = ""
```

Then I get error trying to `import Data.String (lines)`:

```
Module `Data.String' does not export `lines'
```

It would be really nice if such thing is possible. If not, what are best practices for such situations? Where such extensions should be placed?

Thank you.

**Update**

I don't plan to release my extensions as a library, just want to organize it inside my project in a meaningful way.

Comment: In short, you can not extend haskell modules. What is your usecase for this?

Comment: I've described use case in my question. I'm asking for a way to deal with functions I miss from libraries. I don't want to mix it with my common code, since they naturally belongs to libraries.

Comment: Also, your example function is IMO to specific and trivial to be considered for a standard library module. Note that your implementation isn't very idiomatic, I'd prefer `firstToLower (c:cs) = toLower c : cs; firstToLower "" = ""`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, your version is much cleaner, thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, this is not possible. One solution that people [have used in the past](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-extra) is to put your additions in a module with a name like `Data.String.Extra` and release that module on Hackage (if you think that your additions could be useful to other people).

Alternatively, you can [propose your extension for inclusion in the standard library](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Library_submissions).

Comment: I don't plan to release my extensions as a library, just want to organize it inside my project in a meaningful way. I'm likely to follow your advice and place it inside `*.Extra`. Thank you.